# convert pdf pages into images using AWS s3 and Lambda

Tags: node.js, pdf, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, imagemagick

> I am using node 8.1,
>   I want to convert PDF into images using S3 and lambda but the CloudWatch repeatedly giving the following error:
>   "Unable to import module 'index': Error"
>   The below file is named as index.js in the main project folder:

```
const util = require('util');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  const srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const srcKey = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));

  const dstBucket = srcBucket;
  const dstKey = srcKey.replace('.pdf', '.png');

  s3.getObject({Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey}, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      context.done('S3 get object error:', err);
      context.fail(err);
    }

    // conversion start
    gm(response.Body)
      .setFormat("png")
      .resize(200) // you can configure
      .quality(100) // you can configure
      .stream((err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log("gm conversion process error: ");
          console.log(err,stdout,stderr);
          context.fail(err);
        }
        const chunks = [];
        stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        stdout.on('end', () => {
          console.log('gm process finished');
          const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);

          // Upload start
          const params = {
            Bucket: dstBucket,
            Key: dstKey,
            ContentType: 'image/png',
            Body: buffer
          };
          s3.putObject(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("S3 upload error: " + err);
              context.fail(err);
            }
            console.log('S3 upload finished!');
            console.log('Bucket: ' + dstBucket);
            console.log('key: ' + dstKey);
            context.succeed({
              "error":false
            });
          });
        });

        stderr.on('data', (data) => {
          console.log('stderr data: ' +  data);
        });
      });
  });
};
```

> I am not much aware about the aws-lambda as well as the file conversion and this is the only area where I have got stuck and can't find any way to solve the problem.

I think there might be some problem in the index.handler way of passing the functions but I don't know where the minor fault is situated at.

Answer (score 0):

Problem sounds like you didn't configure the .yml file properly.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/serverless-deploy-wt.html#serv-deploy (for the cli to deploy)

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/ (the config file that you need to write so aws knows what to import)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running that code locally? It sounds like an error in Syntax.

Anyways, I’ve created just this functionality and it’s available on fit hub here:

https://github.com/rcastoro/PDFImagine

You can see from the video below it takes PDFs in an s3 bucket, and using an aws event, notifies the lambda function to convert new PDFs into images.

https://youtu.be/yU-jA2_5Tvs